# Check if a user belongs to a group in Odoo

Tags: python, odoo

I'm new to Odoo, i have a selection field and one of the options should be reserved only for a certain groupe, the field's name is event_type and the group's name is TL, i tried this but it doesn't work properly.

```
@api.multi
@api.onchange('event_type')
def _test(self):
    if self.event_type == 'HV':
        if self.env.user.has_group('TL')==False:
            raise ValidationError('Only user belongs to TL are allowed to ....' )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`has_group()` needs a full external ID with module name and the ID itself.

I would also not use `== False` because that is bad style.

```py
@api.multi
@api.onchange('event_type')
def _test(self):
    if self.event_type == 'HV' and\
            not self.env.user.has_group('module_name.external_id'):
        raise ValidationError('Only users with "TL" group rights ...' )
```

Answer (score 1):

You must call group with module name where you defined it :- **module_name.TL**

```
@api.multi
@api.onchange('event_type')
def _test(self):
    if self.event_type == 'HV' and self.user_has_groups('module_name.TL'):
        raise ValidationError('Only user belongs to TL are allowed to ....' )
```